# pandas.Series.nlargest does not work on sub frame/Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame with two series. One of the variables is industry, another one is company return. I can find average return in the industry typing:

```
np.mean(output['returns'].where(output['industry'] == 101))
```

and this works fine. But when I try to find 10 highest return companies using

```
output['returns'].where(output['industry'] == 101).nlargest(10).index
```

it gives me top 10 companies from the total Frame, it does not take `where` into account. Saying differently I need top 10 companies in industry, but get only global top. Does anybody has any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Your second example works as expected for me.